# How do I find my vertex data store path for grounding a chatbot in the studio?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I am trying to ground my vertex generative AI studio chatbot with a vertex data store. The field asks for a vertex data store path and specifies the path format

projects/(project name)/......

I have already created a data store in vertex ai search. How do I identify it's path? The tutorial suggests that I click on more details on the data store page, but no such option is visible.

I am trying to ground my vertex generative AI studio chatbot with a vertex data store. The field asks for a vertex data store path and specifies the path format

projects/(project name)/......

I have already created a data store in vertex ai search. How do I identify it's path? The tutorial suggests that I click on more details on the data store page, but no such option is visible.

Answer (score 0):

Coincidentally I was searching for this today and also saw your question on Reddit haha

`projects/PROJECT_ID/locations/global/collections/default_collection/dataStores/DATA_STORE_NAME`

**Note**: It is `project_ID` not `project_NAME`, but for data store, use the name. You should be able to switch between projects by clicking on your current project name in the top left corner, it'll also show you the project ID.

Locations are the settings you have chosen for your datastore and collections should just be default_collection unless you specify.

Cheers!